# Not able to identify element display values

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope

I have photo gallery type of web page. It is comprised of grid of photo thumbnails, with assigned tags beneath them.

At top of page is a list of all of the tags, formatted as buttons. User can click on one or more tag buttons to filter photos. I am using Isotope js for this filtering. This works fine.

However I want to add new feature that runs after the Isotope filtering that will hide any tag buttons that are not assigned to any of the remaining filtered photos.

My plan was to do following:

1. identify all visible photos
2. create array from visible photos' tags
3. use array to hide any unmatched tags

However, I am having problems identifying visible photos after I click tag buttons and Isotope does its filtering.

It seemed like it would be quite straightforward. Isotope js changes a specified element's `display = "none"` for the hidden photos. Eg if I inspect the element, I can see hidden elements have `display = "none"`

I created a 'visibletags' function that is called at end of tag button `on click` to find elements where `display != "none"`:

```
$('.filter-button').on('click', function() { 
    // isotope code here 
    // isotope hides some photos setting their div's `display = "none"` 

    visibletags();
}

function visibletags(){
    var imgdivs = document.querySelectorAll('.imgdiv');
    var showtags = [];

    for (var i=0, max=imgdivs.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (window.getComputedStyle(imgdivs[i]).display != "none") {
            // this should be a div that is not hidden by Isotope js 
            // so loop through it's tags to build array
            // array will be used later to hide unmatched tags 
            var phototagspans = imgdivs[i].querySelectorAll('.photo-tag');              
            for (var j=0, max=phototagspans.length; j < max; j++) { 
                showtags.push(phototagspans[j].className);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not able to identify the element's `display` value. I have tried using `window.getComputedStyle(imgdivs[i]).display`,  `imgdivs[i].display` and `imgdivs[i].style.display`

Edited to modify question:

I tested running the 'visibletags()' function as another button on click event that I manually click after the isotope filtering is complete. This successfully gets all photo element display values. So that part of code does work.

So my question now is how to run 'visibletags()' function after the Isotope filtering in a way that it is one complete set of code?

I tried changing the 'visibletags()' function to run as `$('.filter-button').mouseup(function()` but didn't get filtering results.

Maybe this is now general Javascript question eg how to get `on click` event's results after they have been rendered?

Comment: Why don't you use jquery in this function as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Isotope, but you probably need to use a callback function. Check out this documentation, especially the `layoutComplete` part: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html

In your case, the result could be something like this:

```
$('.filter-button').on('click', function() { 
  // initialize isotope
  $isotope.on('layoutComplete', function() {
    visibletags();
  });
  // other isotope code here 
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks! For other readers, `$isotope` will be name of your 'grid' or grouping of elements that are being manipulated by Isotope. In my case it was `$grid`. Also, both Isotope callback events `arrangeComplete` and `layoutComplete` worked too.